# Cannot force WebBrowser Control to render using current version of IE

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, internet-explorer

I need the WebBrowser Control in my Windows Forms application to render pages using the *latest* version of Internet Explorer, or atleast the latest version that is installed on my machine - which is IE 11.

A few weeks ago, before I began working on this project I came across a website called DevDocs.io, and in IE 11 it works. However, even after applying the registry hack I cannot view DevDocs.io in the WebBrowser control because apparently I am using an "Unsupported" browser. It then goes on to say that I need to use either Firefox, Chrome or IE 10+. I thought I was using IE 10+ since I had added the DWORD to the registry.

I've come across *many* websites that just don't display or behave normally due to the fact that the WebBrowser control still isn't rendering in IE11, or 10, or 9...

There are two things I would like to know:

- Is there a method or class that exposes the rendering engine being used by the WebBrowser Control?
- Why isn't the DWORD Registry hack working, and how do I get it to work?

To be clear, I have gone to the Registry, and looked up: `HKEY LOCAL MACHINE > SOFTWARE > MICROSOFT > INTERNET EXPLORER > MAIN > FEATURE CONTROL > FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` and added a DWORD with values `myApp.exe` and `11000`.

The 11000 is to get it to render using IE11, as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28VS.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add your registry key under both the main (64bit) node and the 32bit node, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl`

You should then visit http://webdbg.com/ua.aspx to verify the document mode and UA string.

Comment: That did it! Thank you @EricLaw. I had given up on this project until your answer came along. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here the method that I usually use and works for me (both for 32 bit and 64 bit applications):

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        if (!mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), false))
        {
            //another application instance is running
            return;
        }
        try
        {

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            var targetApplication = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName  + ".exe";
            int ie_emulation = 10000;
            try
            {
                string tmp = Properties.Settings.Default.ie_emulation;
                ie_emulation = int.Parse(tmp);
            }
            catch { }
            SetIEVersioneKeyforWebBrowserControl(targetApplication, ie_emulation);

            m_webLoader = new FormMain();

            Application.Run(m_webLoader);
        }
        finally
        {
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
    }

    private static void SetIEVersioneKeyforWebBrowserControl(string appName, int ieval)
    {
        RegistryKey Regkey = null;
        try
        {


            Regkey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true);

            //If the path is not correct or 
            //If user't have priviledges to access registry 
            if (Regkey == null)
            {
                YukLoggerObj.logWarnMsg("Application FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION Failed - Registry key Not found");
                return;
            }

            string FindAppkey = Convert.ToString(Regkey.GetValue(appName));

            //Check if key is already present 
            if (FindAppkey == "" + ieval)
            {
                YukLoggerObj.logInfoMsg("Application FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION already set to " + ieval);
                Regkey.Close();
                return;
            }

            //If key is not present or different from desired, add/modify the key , key value 
            Regkey.SetValue(appName, unchecked((int)ieval), RegistryValueKind.DWord);

            //check for the key after adding 
            FindAppkey = Convert.ToString(Regkey.GetValue(appName));

            if (FindAppkey == "" + ieval)
                YukLoggerObj.logInfoMsg("Application FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION changed to " + ieval + "; changes will be visible at application restart");
            else
                YukLoggerObj.logWarnMsg("Application FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION setting failed; current value is  " + ieval);



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            YukLoggerObj.logWarnMsg("Application FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION setting failed; " + ex.Message);

        }
        finally
        {
            //Close the Registry 
            if (Regkey != null)
                Regkey.Close();
        }


    }
```