# WebBrowser don't update Element at realtime

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a WebBrowser in a winform project, when i load a page that containing a dynamique élement like à clock, it's not updated at real time, as is the case in other browsers (Chrome, IE and FireFox).

there is a way to have the same behavior in my WebBrowser ?

my end goal is to get a value of the element (Time Server) and to synchronize my local time with the serveur with the nearest second.

Answer (score 0):

Try Firefox browser control instead of default browser control.

You can do it by importing dll to your toolbox

you can take help from following URl [See this](https://code.google.com/p/geckofx/)

Comment: thank's for your replay, I solved my problem following the solution proposed for this question [Cannot force WebBrowser Control to render using current version of IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23356194/cannot-force-webbrowser-control-to-render-using-current-version-of-ie) so, by adding ma application to KEY inline `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl`

However your track interests me and I will look over