# Updating to recent version of IE on webbrowser control to run local jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, winforms, internet-explorer

I have studied the several questions relating to this topic([Cannot force WebBrowser Control to render using current version of IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23356194/cannot-force-webbrowser-control-to-render-using-current-version-of-ie) ,[Use latest version of Internet Explorer in the webbrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922308/use-latest-version-of-internet-explorer-in-the-webbrowser-control)) but my C# knowledge is too basic to find out where I should be placing this 'fix' in my code.

I am using visual studio 2015 and writing a winforms application in C#. The application consists of a web browser that displays local HTML files, some of which are using jquery and javascript. I know I have to edit the registry but I have no clue on how to go about this safely. The code provided in the second link seems good, but I don't know what to change in it so it applies to my project and where to place it in my code.

my Form1.cs so far.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Web_Browser
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }



        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            this.webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(String.Format("file:///{0}/post-op/index.html", curDir));
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void navigateToPage()
        {
            var filemapping = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "www.xy.com", "file:///{0}/XY/index.html" },
            { "www.post-op.com", "file:///{0}/post-op/index.html" },
            { "www.free-mail.com", "file:///{0}/mail/index.html"},
            { "test", "file:///{0}/index.html" },

        };

            var textEntered = textBox1.Text;

            string filename;
            if (filemapping.TryGetValue(textEntered, out filename))
            {
                string curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
                var uri = new Uri(String.Format(filename, curDir));
                webBrowser1.Navigate(uri);
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            navigateToPage();
        }

        private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                navigateToPage();
            }
        }

        private void backButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.GoBack();
        }

        private void forwardButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.GoForward();
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            this.webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(String.Format("file:///{0}/mail/index.html", curDir));
        }


    }
}
```

Sorry if this seems stupid. I have really tried to solve this issue on my own with the answers already given on the several questions on SO, but i'm a bit lost atm.

Comment: [How can I get the WebBrowser control to show modern contents?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38514184/3110834)

Comment: @RezaAghaei Perfect! that was really well written. Thanks a lot!